# Will I get banned if my Eggs are hatching without walking

Tags: pokemon-go

I've noticed that the distance traveled on my eggs is constantly rising, even when my phone is sat firmly on my desk.

I've worked out that it takes roughly 6 minutes for each 0.01km, so over my average work day of 8 hours, I would be gaining around 0.8km without moving, maybe 1.0 if I pick it up a few times. (Excuse me if my calculation was off, maths isn't my strong point)

[image: Eggs showing distance tracker]

From watching my screen it looks like I am losing connection to the GPS and is thinking I am moving whilst recalculating.

My question here is if I continue to allow my game to do this, do I risk getting banned from the game, or is this normal behavior which is tolerated? (I don't want to risk an auto-ban just because I want to use the Pokestop close by where I work)

Comment: This is just GPS wander, it's fine. It happens to everyone.

Comment: We have no idea of knowing whether you will be banned or not.  We're not Niantic.

Comment: Hi @Frank, i was hoping to find if anyone had heard of bans etc.. I know it is unlikely anyone would know Niantics banning policies and procedures.

Comment: Seems like kind of a ridiculous question, but it's well written and has a good picture, so here's an upvote.

Comment: Hearing of bans is one thing.  We deal in objective and definitive information, which we can't do for this kind of question.  There's no way to tell if you will be banned or not, unless Niantic says something about it.  Therefore, I'm voting to close as developer intent.

Comment: OK, fair enough, I just like to know the reason so that I don't fall in to the same trap again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This normal behavior is tolerated since this happens to a lot of people. Only way you can get banned in this game is if you spoof your location and this doesn't even come close to that! I've even caught the occasional pokemon because my GPS was off for a second.

Comment: I'm just reading up on this now. Do you know if this is an issue with the game, or with my phone?

Comment: It's just a slight GPS issue when it is re-calibrating your position which is normal in ALL phones. The way this game detects cheaters is if you suddenly travel long distances very fast and in your cause you're easily within 100 meters of your actual location.

Comment: Ah, so I'm fine hovering around my workplace, but if I nip to shanghai during my lunch I will get banned?

Comment: Yup! Since the game uses GPS to check distance traveled it just assumes you're walking around which is fine.

Comment: I believe the ban is placed if you travel more than 40km in a short amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will be fine and you won't get banned for it. GPS in phones isn't always great, especially around areas with tall buildings.

You can also hatch your egg by cycling or running. Pretty much anything under 30 km/h will work fine. If you go over this speed (e.g. by car or train) then it won't count and you temporarily won't be able to interact with Poke Stops.